# Inconspicuous microSD card adapter for MacBook Pro

Tags: sd-card

Does a microSD adapter exist that doesn't stick out of the MacBook Pro SD card slot?  I don't want to live in fear of breaking the SD card off while carrying around my laptop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this is an old question but I just found it via a Google search. Check out the Nifty MiniDrive which is exactly what you are describing.

http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1342319572/the-nifty-minidrive

Comment: You are the new best answer. You answered before Richard.  I wonder if the inventor ever saw my question.

Answer (score 4):

Check out this low profile micro SD card reader for the Raspberry Pi computer:
http://www.adafruit.com/products/966

$6 versus $25 for the Kickstarter polished Nifty Drive (I actually bought one for a friend).

Comment: The above mentioned Raspberry Pi converters, with a hinge, on a too thick circuit, might possible work (although I doubt it), but IF they'll "fit", they certainly will damage your slot, as it does NOT fit correctly, and will forge the other end inside (besides it will be hard to remove them). Not a good alternative.

Answer (score 3):

I think the Nifty MiniDrive might be exactly what you're looking for:

http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1342319572/the-nifty-minidrive

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like a half-length SD card->microSD adapter? If you want to use that slot, the card is going to stick out--you're probably not allowed to license the SD spec without making the card that size.

However, there are some incredibly small USB drives/card readers that are bigger inside the port than they are outside. This [microSD card reader](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002HGFKR8)'s slot is *inside* the usb port, and this is a [USB drive with a similar form factor](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0041O200O).

Answer (score 0):

there are tons of sd/micro sd card readers that usb but they have the same danger. the only alternative is to use a usb extension to plug one of those in, but it still sticks out like any usb cord and can still damage ur usb port. i recommend just sticking to a micro sd to sd adapter and just use caution when using the card